# JFET Vgs Calculation Equation

Tags: resistors, bias, jfet, variable

Does anyone know the formula to calculate the Vgs of a JFET used as a variable resistor?
Say, I have a Vds of 24v and I require a current of 20mA (just arbitrary values) I would need a 1.2k resistance, how would I calculate the Vgs to get that resistance value?

Comment: It does not work like that, the JFET behaves similar to a **current source** (not a resistor). The drain current of the JFET (assuming \$V_{DS}\$ is high enough) depends on the model JFET and its \$V_{GS}\$. Often the drain current is only specified when \$V_{GS}\$ = 0 V.

Comment: [Equations 6.39 and 6.40](https://coefs.uncc.edu/dlsharer/files/2012/04/J3a.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Andy's link, we differentiate the equation # 6.39,
with respect to \$V_{DS}\$.

We want the resistance. That requires incremental \$V_\mathrm{Drain}/I_\mathrm{Drain}\$.

We end up with a constant portion: 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}I_D}{\mathrm{d} V_{DS}} = 2 K (V_{GS} - V_P)
$$
and a variable portion: 
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\mathrm{d}I_D}{\mathrm{d} V_{DS}} &= K 2 (2 V_{DS}) \\
&= 4 K V_{DS}
\end{split}
$$
The constant portion is the transconductance, or the inverse of channel resistance.

The variable portion is the DISTORTION.

Comment: Nice derivation.

Comment: with thanks to who-ever edited the equations for legibility

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the JFET can be used as a controllable "quasi-linear" resistor (between the nodes D and S) within the following limitations:

1.) The drain-source voltage VDS must be small enough.
In practice: VDS<(VGS-VP) and for "good" linearity: **VDS<<(VGS-VP)**,

2.) The source node must be at ground potential or at "virtual ground" (inverting opamp input). Therefore, the gate voltage VG is the control voltage

3.) The value of RDS=f(VGS) is as given in analogsystemsrfs answer.